# Python - Not processing str in for loop - result white

Tags: python

I´m have a problem in processing one argument in loop from python.

def Find_files(*args):
for item in args:
        for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(item)):
            print(files)

The result is it white.
down code complete:

```
print(directorys)
type(directorys)

0       \\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\z$\\Directory-LOG
1    \\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\x$\\Directory-LOG
2    \\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\y$\\Directory-LOG
Name: IPDIRETORIO, dtype: object

pandas.core.series.Series
```

#

```
def Find_files(*args):
    # Lista todos os arquivos em todos os diretórios
    for item in args:
        for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(item)):
            print(files)
```

#

```
Find_files(directorys[0])
```

"result is it white"

```
type(directorys[0])
str
```

#

but, if I set argument in item conform down, process with success:

```
Find_files('\\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\z$\\Directory-LOG')
```

I don´t understend what problem.

can you help me?

Comment: Are you asking why passing the value from the list is returning nothing while passing it directly as a string is? I believe the value stored in the list is "0       \\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\z$\\Directory-LOG". You should split it and only get the full_path of the directory - remove the zero and space before you pass it.

Comment: exactly. 

the zero is removed in call function: print(directorys[0])
\\\\192.168.30.37\\m$\\CL01-INST01-BKP-LOG

Answer (score -1):

Descovered the problem.

My code was wrong. Had additional backslashes

```
the exit should be:
"\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\z$\Directory-LOG"

Instead of:

"\\\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\\z$\\Directory-LOG"
```